# Codesign returns exit code of 11 for xcode iphone project -- can't find documentation on exit code 11

Tags: iphone, xcode, codesign

I'm new to iPhone development.  I am trying to get Xcode to run an application on a phone.

The app works fine in the simulator.  Initially I hit the error:
The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

I followed the steps here:
[The executable was signed with invalid entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074546/the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements)

But now I am getting an exit code of 11.  I checked the documentation on codesign but I can't find any mention of an exit code 11 (http://gemma.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html)

Below is the log I am getting.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I am using iPhone OS 3.1.3.

Build HubPages of project HubPages with configuration Debug

CodeSign build/Debug-iphoneos/HubPages.app
cd /Users/larryfreeman/src/hub/mobile/HubPages/build/iphone
setenv IGNORE_CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_RADAR_7181968 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Larry Freeman (LT6G4W62Z2)" --resource-rules=/Users/larryfreeman/src/hub/mobile/HubPages/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos/HubPages.app/Entitlements.plist --entitlements /Users/larryfreeman/src/hub/mobile/HubPages/build/iphone/build/HubPages.build/Debug-iphoneos/HubPages.build/HubPages.xcent /Users/larryfreeman/src/hub/mobile/HubPages/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos/HubPages.app

Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 11

Thanks!

-Larry

Comment: Larry were you able to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 11 is SIGSEGV - codesign crashed with a segmentation fault.

Maybe try removing & re-adding your certificates & recreating the entitlements.plist file?