# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The executable was signed with invalid entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074546/the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements)

I have made a app but I am unable to deploy on my device because every time it show an error The executable was signed with invalid entitlements and stop deploying plz tell me the procedure how can I solve the problem.

Comment: I posted an answet that worked for me here, check it to see if it works for you too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333034/im-still-getting-the-the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements-erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File->New File->Code Signing and add Entitlements file to your project.

Comment: This error does not necessarily require creating the entitlements file. I have this error & my entitlements file is fine.