# Xcode with iPhone 4 Development: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

The complete error message is:

> #### The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
>
> The executable
> was signed with invalid entitlements. The entitlements specified in
> your application's Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those
> specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

I have already spent a couple of hours resolving this error message but haven't resolved it yet. Basically, I have made my iPhone-4.0 for development and installed the valid provisioning profile from my account on developer.apple.com.

We have our main application, which is signed with the same provisioning profile, and it works fine, but when I try running application given in the http://teachyourselfiphone.com/ book for learning and testing purposes, it just doesn't work.

I have tried all of the following things, but nothing works.

1. [The executable was signed with invalid entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074546/the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements)
2. http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2010/11/executable-was-signed-with-invalid.html

Could anyone please help me to get rid of this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was getting this error today. The issue was that the provisioning profile on the project was different to the provisioning profile on the target.

Go to the project settings and make sure the provisioning profile is one that matches your current application identifier

Then go to the target settings and make sure that it is the same setup.

Comment: Thanks Eamonn, for me just cleaning up solution and rebuilding worked fine. We have all our iPhone devices with same developer certificate installed.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. For anyone who recently switched their project around to have multiple targets that require different provisioning profiles: 

Set the Project -> Build Settings -> Code Signing to "Don't Code Sign"; set each Target's -> Build Settings to their desired configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the ideas.

As I had a different reason, I want to share it as well:

Bought a new device, which I restored from a backup of my old one. Having the same name, iTunes and XCode also copied all the provisiong profiles.

I forgot, that, even if the device is called the same, (and my provisioning profile was including this name) it is a different device id and it does not work on this device until you include this as well in your provisioning profile, update, download and install in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with this error on my Mac machine:

> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.  (0xE8008016).

That time I checked the `identifier` in `xcode -> Targets -> "XXXX"(project name) -> GetInfo`. In the Properties tab I had mentioned the wrong identifier value. After changing it the correct app identifier value it worked properly.

Answer (score 2):

I was using distribution profile rather than developer profile... :P

Comment: why the down vote? sometimes people make mistakes like this, and this answer does give a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error message too. It was on one of my apps already in store that I wanted to update. I ran 'clean all targets' after hours of re-downloading expired profiles and that did the trick. 
Good luck with your efforts - frustrating isn't it?

Comment: Yes it was frustrating but now everything looks good..! Also Apple doesn't allow you to test the application with your Distribution Certificate. You have to use developer certificate to test your app and just before submitting you change it to distribution certificate...!! So far no issues but you never know that might cause some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue ... I figured this out... There are apparently a lot of things that can happen to cause this issue.  This was my particular flavor so you may or may not find this useful...it is just one more thing to check. I thought I would post the solution so when I am trying to figure this out next year I can find my post and fix it ;)  Also if anyone else see a similar problem they can find this and maybe it is what they are seeing... My particular problem was I did not catch all the places that need to be updated.  I got two out of three which may be close but we're not playing horseshoes here ;)  Before you ridicule me just remember hind sight is 20/20...and I'm old and can't remember stuff I probably figured out last year.

There are several areas to check to make sure your provisioning profile is updated.

First there is the new developer identity certificate.  Make sure this is put into your keychain.  Mine is under Keychains - login in the Key Chain Access app on the Mac.
Next you need the new provisioning profile on the device.  Delete out your expired ones and get a new one generated through the use of your new developer identity.  Do this through the XCode4 Organizer.  Trust the warnings in Organizer that a valid certificate cannot be found...
Finally, this is the one I missed, update the Library Provisioning Profiles!  Again through XCode4 Organizer above "DEVICES" there is a "LIBRARY" section select "Provisioning Profiles" delete out your old expired profiles and add your new provisioning profiles.

The big hint was in the project build settings - the code signing area tells you what provisioning profile the signing matches.  Mine said "currently matches..." and then listed an older profile that was different from the new one I was putting on the device.  Even though that older profile was not expired it was - I believe - based on the old developer identity which had expired last night.  So I think the problem was XCode was signing with that older provisioning profile and the device had the newer provisioning profile and so I get the really clear error message above ;) ...

I was looking for this for hours and hope I can save someone a bit of time.  I am sure I will be looking for this next year when I screw it up again.

Note to self: I told you that you were going to mess this up next year...and here it is next year and you are reading this post.

This same post is at: https://devforums.apple.com/message/425569

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I updated my phone to an iPhone 6 and restored it from my iPhone 4S backup. I wound up with provisioning profiles from my old phone which had to be deleted. You can no longer remove profiles in Settings->General->Profiles in iOS 8 - look here for instructions: [Removing provisional profile with ios 8 and Xcode 6.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996789/removing-provisional-profile-with-ios-8-and-xcode-6-0-1). I had to then manually download the team provisioning profile and install it using the same instructions as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change anything related to certificates (didn't replace or update them) just do a `Product -> Clean`. It helped me several times. (Xcode 6.2)