# Removing provisional profile with ios 8 and Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I cannot seem to remove the provisional profiles on my device using iOS 8 General settings since the profile selection is gone.  Xcode 6.0.1 also does not allow for removing provisional profiles.  Anyone know how to remove provisional profiles on a device running iOS 8  and Xcode 6.0.1?

Answer (score 9):

It´s a little bit hidden in Xcode 6:

1. Open Xcode and go to Window --> Devices via the menu bar
2. On the left pane right click on your device
3. Choose option "Show Provisioning Profiles ..."
4. Delete the installed Provisioning Profile via the "-" button

That´s it.

Comment: Thanks Paul, your method was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: I cannot see this button. iPhone 6 8.1.2 (12B440) Any ideas? http://tinypic.com/r/2gvptzs/8

Comment: @EvgeniPetrov try a right click e.g. "secondary click" with two fingers on your touch pad.

Comment: Just for anyone else who was confused by paul's comment, he's saying to right click (secondary click) on your device on the left hand side and the menu will show "Show Provisioning Profiles..." and upon selection of that you will see a list of the device's installed profiles. Same idea as the answer by Allivizhi

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode:

1. *Window* menu —> *Devices*
2. Choose the desired device from left panel
3. On the bottom of the left pane there is a settings icon. Use it to select *show provisioning profiles*
4. In the list of all the provisioning profiles installed on your device(s), add or delete it.

Comment: I can not seem to uninstall provisioning profiles. They are there in Devices however can not remove. I also do not see any profiles option in Settings -> General on my iPhone 6. Anyone have any help on this?