# XCode4 : Uploading App Problem

Tags: xcode, file-upload, xcode4, uploading

I'm getting this error while trying to upload my via XCode4:

[BEROR]CodeSign error: The entitlements file '/Users/fgringo/Desktop/SecretBalls_V1.2/iPhone Developer: Felipe Silva (JSZ86XLUAW)
9FBB7371-A3F7-42C6-95CC-5E54A26FBA3A' is missing

I tryed all the other topics, the errors go different, so this was the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building for Ad-hoc distribution make sure your project is setup to include an Entitlements.plist file.

See: [The executable was signed with invalid entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074546/the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements)